# What is the purpose of double colons in Lua?

Tags: lua, special-characters, goto

I have been aware that version 5.3 for Lua had come out not too long ago but hadn't had a reason to visit the documentation online until now.  I may be wrong, but I do not believe to remember the usage of the double-colons `::` like it is used so abundantly there.

I see that it is considered a "special token" like others are (greater than, less than, asterisks, etc) but I know what those are for.

What is the purpose of using them in Lua?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`::` is only used for one thing in Lua *:

[Declaring labels for jumping with `goto`.](//www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.4)

```
goto label
::label::
```

> The `goto` statement transfers the program control to a label. For syntactical reasons, labels in Lua are considered statements too:
>
> ```
> stat ::= goto Name
> stat ::= label
> label ::= ‘::’ Name ‘::’
> ```
>
> A label is visible in the entire block where it is defined, except inside nested blocks where a label with the same name is defined and inside nested functions. A goto may jump to any visible label as long as it does not enter into the scope of a local variable.
>
> Labels and empty statements are called *void statements*, as they perform no actions.

<sub>* I don't consider extensive use with extended BNF in the documentation use in Lua itself.</sub>

Comment: Ah, ok.  So my real question should have been concerning `goto` statements!  Now I know where to put more of my attention to.

Comment: Well, naturally the normal advice regarding `goto` holds: Don't use it, aside from breaking multiple loops, unless it really makes your code more readable. Most of the time, it doesn't.